# CMIS query language; Queryname cmis:document

Tags: cmis

I have some problems with CMIS query language. I want to get all documents (table no important), which have some property. So I wrote Select my_property from cmis:document.

Unfortunately I get answer: 0 documents. But when I alter query to Select my_property from my_table. I get different answer.

Could you tell me why?

Comment: can you please provide some more details, such as which server you're querying and which actual queries you're using?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the spec does not provide for it. Here is what the spec says about the "relational view projection" ([source](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/errata-01/os/cmis-spec-v1.0-errata-01-os-complete.html#_Toc243905421)):

> In each Virtual Table, a Virtual Column is implicitly defined for each
>   property defined in the Object-Type Definition AND for all properties
>   defined on ANY ancestor-type of the Object-Type but NOT defined in the
>   Object-Type definition.

So a given object-type can be queried for properties of ancestor types, but the spec makes no provision for querying an object-type for properties of descendent types, which is what you are trying to do.

Jeff